# Ad-hoc distributed applications after membership expiration

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

I have an Apple Developer Program membership. My membership expires in a few days, but the provisioning profile expires in three months. I distributed an application to a few people using the Ad-hoc distribution and this provisioning profile. Will my apps continue to function after my membership expires?

In addition, is it possible to use the generated certificate to sign apps for ad-hoc distribution after the expiration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this would answer your question:

**Regarding Provision profile:**
- Ad hoc profiles last for a year. 
- Development build profiles last for 3 months.
*Thus In your case until your profile is not expired you would be able to distribute your app using it. If you have already prepared the build & shared with valid provision profile then until it gets expired it should work. But once your certificate gets expired you can't use the same to prepare new builds & distribute.*

**From the apple developer support center certificates section:**

> iOS Distribution Certificate (In-house, Internal Use Apps)
>   Users will no longer be able to run apps that have been signed with
>   this certificate. You must distribute a new version of your app that
>   is signed with a new certificate.

Here are the cases for AppStore approved Apps when certificate gets expired.

**Apple Push Notification Service Certificate**

You can no longer send push notifications to your app.

**iOS Distribution Certificate (App Store)**

If your iOS Developer Program membership is valid, your existing apps on the App Store will not be affected. However, you will no longer be able to submit new apps or updates to the App Store.

**iOS Distribution Certificate (In-house, Internal Use Apps)**

Users will no longer be able to run apps that have been signed with this certificate. You must distribute a new version of your app that is signed with a new certificate.

> If your membership expires, your apps will no longer be available for purchase and will not appear in search results on the App Store. However, if you renew your membership after it has expired, your apps will be available for purchase on the App Store within 24 hours. You do not need to resubmit your apps.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer! So, I'm able to sign and distribute even after my membership expires, until my certificate expires?

Comment: Yes. You can.

For your reference:
If your membership expires, users can still download, install, and run your Developer ID–signed applications. However, once your Developer ID certificate expires, you must be a Mac Developer Program member to get new Developer ID certificates to sign updates and new applications.

https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/

Comment: I have a follow-up question: Let's say that my certificate will expire in two weeks and I prepare a new version, signed with a new certificate and profile (same Bundle ID). Can users install this new version without uninstalling the previous version?